# I did not dowload the keystore when I created my etherwallet account

Tags: keystore

Last year I created a account in my etherwallet, when it finished, i just saved the address of wallet and password,did not save keystore file also private key. Now I access in my etherwallet, they require the keystore or private key, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

No ways. You was have to save v3/JSON file or private key. ETH address built on public key. This why you can't be able to use this address anymore.